# Comparing lines of strings from a file

Tags: c++

I have a file that I have read and I want to read each individual line as if it were a string and compare each line to find certain keywords and if I find those certain keywords, take everything within those keywords and make a new string out of it. It is possible to have more than one line with the same keywords, so I would like to create separate strings...

I have some ugly looking code right now that it would be embarrassing to put here, can someone point me in the right direction of how to do this...

I can put my code here if you like, but I'll have to explain it a lot.

> AGU UAC AUU GCG CGA UGG GCC UCG AGA CCC GGG UUU AAA GUA GGU GA
>
> GUU ACA UUG CGC GAU GGG CCU CGA GAC CCG GGU UUA AAG UAG GUG A
>
> UUA CAU UGC GCG  M  GGC CUC GAG ACC CGG GUU UAA AGU AGG UGA
>
> UGG  M  AAA UUU GGG CCC AGA GCU CCG GGU AGC GCG UUA CAU UGA

This would be part of my text file. I want to find 'M' and then find instances of: 1) UAA, 2) UAG, or 3) UGA. And make each one a separate string so that I can compare their lengths. I tried using the assignment operator, but it would print out the same string every time.

ED. I guess what I would like to do is just find any instance of 'M', when I do, I would like to make that whole line into a string so I can compare the strings.

```
ifstream code_File ("example.txt");   // open text file.
if (code_File.is_open()) {
    while (code_File.good()) {


        getline(code_File,line);    //get the contents of file 
        cout  << line << endl;     // output contents of file on screen.


            found = line.find_first_of('M', 0);               // Finding start code
        if (found != string::npos) {
           code_Assign.assign(line, int(found), 100);        //assign the line to code_Assign and print out string from where I found the start code 'M'.

            cout << endl << "code_Assign: " << code_Assign << endl << endl;
```

Comment: I guess it has really nothing to do with Xcode except the fact that I am using Xcode. I shall not use it anymore.

Comment: @user1046825: I'm afraid you should show either code or _precise_ examples of desired input,output pairs. _"`I want to find M and then find instances of: 1) UAA, 2) UAG, or 3) UGA.`"_ doesn't mean anything. Likewise, _"`using the assignment operator`"_ doesn't add any information.

Comment: So from there I would like to find first instance of 'M'. I do, however, it finds all instances and the string code_Assign will get replace with the new string it finds.

Answer (score 1):

That seems a good task for `grep` or `sed` or `awk` standard Posix utilities.

If you want it (faster) inside a program, consider using standard [parsing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing) techiques e.g. with [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/)

Answer (score 0):

It's not at all clear to me what you are trying to do, however:

To read a line and put it in a single string: use `std::getline`.

To find a fixed string in another string, use `std::search`; for more
complicated patterns, use `boost::regex` (or `std::regex` if you have a
C++11 compiler).  `std::search` will return an iterator, and two
iterators can be used to construct a new string.  The `regex` solutions
can “capture”, so you have access to the intervening string
directly (or not; a lot depends on how complicated the pattern is, and 
the `regex` solution doesn't work when the string you want to capture is
in a repeated pattern).  Without more information, however, it is
difficult to say more.

Try specifying your problem precisely; I think you'll find that that
helps in finding a solution.

Comment: Okay, well first off, using that blocked off piece above. Assuming that is my text file, how would I extract each line as a string?

Comment: And specifically how do i use std::getline? I am using it at the moment and it is taking the contents of the whole file...

Comment: @user1046825 `std::getline(source, line)` should only read up until the next `'\n'`.  Is there something funny about the file?  (Unix line endings, and you're on a Windows machine---although that's always worked for me.)